# UPDATE scipt to remove email address form Distribution List column

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2016

I have a table column like the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EXAMPLE;
CREATE TABLE #EXAMPLE(DistributionList VARCHAR(250));

INSERT INTO #EXAMPLE
values
('x@x.com; y@y.co.uk; me@me.com;'), 
('me@me.com; a@a.com;'), 
('me@me.com;'), 
('NULL'), 
('z@z.com; me@me.com;'), 
('NULL'), 
('c@c.co.uk; me@me.com; xx@x.com;'), 
('NULL');

SELECT *
FROM   #EXAMPLE;
```

How do I strip out 'me@me.com' from each of the values in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try** `REPLACE`

```
UPDATE #EXAMPLE 
SET DistributionList = NULLIF(NULLIF(REPLACE(DistributionList, 'me@me.com;', ''), ''), ';')
FROM #EXAMPLE
WHERE DistributionList like '%me@me.com%'
```